# How to set 2 criteria in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

What I want to do is print column C to column H if A=F and B=G

LibreOffice:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

=[**SUMIFS**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_sumifs.html)(C:C;A:A;F1;B:B;G1)

or

=[**MAXIFS**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_maxifs.html)(C:C;A:A;F1;B:B;G1)